# biber/biblatex: \printbibliography spits out section heading despite filters/checks

Tags: biblatex, subdividing, biber

With a setup as reproduced below, I end up with a section heading "Book Chapters" being produced although there is no bib entry to be printed. This leaves me (in my complete setting) with a bunch of empty headings for empty bib sections.

A sample document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,%
backend=biber,%
language=english,%
isbn=false,%
url=true,%
maxbibnames=99%
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@inbook{my:key,
  author    = {AAA BBB and CCC DDD},
  title     = {An Introduction},
  year      = {2012},
  booktitle = {YYY},
  pages     = {111-222},
  publisher = {LePub},
  series    = {The Series},
  keywords   = {authored}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\defbibfilter{bookChapters}{%
  type=inbook or type=incollection
}

\defbibcheck{byYear}{%
  \iffieldint{year}
  {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2013}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}
  {\skipentry}
}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title={Book Chapters},%
  heading=subbibliography,%
  check=byYear,%
  keyword=authored,%
  sorting=ydnt,%
  filter=bookChapters]

\end{document}
```

I crawled the biblatex reference, but it did not come up with a solution for me. I am running biber 1.1 and biblatex 2.1.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: biblatex doesn't know your bibliography is empty at the time the heading is printed. Filtering is done on a per-item basis; empty bibliographies are detected once the last item is processed.

Comment: Thx for your response. Maybe I must clarify: My bibliography (*.bib) is _not_ empty. In the above scenario, the filter "byYear" does not leave a single entry to be printed. How should I determine upfront whether there will be any matching entries in a given bib? That defeats the purpose of filtering, doesn't it?

Comment: I should add: I apply the biblatex filtering in an automated manner to a series of *.bib resources that I cannot change/control upfront.

Comment: The purpose of filtering is to omit some entries, not all of them. You can filter by category instead. Entries can be counted and added to categories in `\AtDataInput`.

Comment: Mmmh. Is \AtDataInput the recommended way to exclude (and to omit) all entries which date prior to a certain year so that \printbibliography does *not* print, actually, in case of an empty bib? So, to clarify, I create a helper category which stores all entries passing the year check in \AtDataInput ... and then I pass category=... to \printbibliography=

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a solution based on \DeclareSourcemap and an auxiliary keyword. I observed that keyword= constraints will have \printbibliography, well, not printing (including the section heading) if a required keyword is not present in any of the entries. Exactly the behavior, I was looking for.

Therefore, I refactored my initial year check ("byYear" above) into a \map statement:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=year,
      match=\regexp{^20(0[8-9]|[1-9][0-9])$},
      final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{^}, replace=\regexp{recent,}]
    }
  }
}
```

(which, here, inserts a keyword "recent" for all entries having a year value between 2008-2099)

The rewritten example of above is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,%
backend=biber,%
language=english,%
isbn=false,%
url=true,%
maxbibnames=99%
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@inbook{my:key,
  author    = {AAA BBB and CCC DDD},
  title     = {An Introduction},
  year      = {2007},
  booktitle = {YYY},
  pages     = {111-222},
  publisher = {LePub},
  series    = {The Series},
  keywords   = {authored}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=year,
      match=\regexp{^20(0[8-9]|[1-9][0-9])$},
      final]
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{^}, replace=\regexp{recent,}]
    }
  }
}


\defbibfilter{bookChapters}{%
  type=inbook or type=incollection
}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title={Book Chapters since 2008},%
  heading=subbibliography,%
  keyword=authored,%
  keyword=recent,%
  sorting=ydnt,%
  filter=bookChapters]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please tell me how I write a `\regexp` that will give me the range 1912--2099? Thanks a million!